# Оформление вопросов. Ставить запятые или вопросительные знаки?

Tags: пунктуация

Что мне теперь делать() и до какого числа нужно принести документы() и нужно ли вообще?

Answer (score 1):

Корректно: Что мне теперь делать и до какого числа нужно принести документы?  И нужно ли вообще?

Запятая не нужна. В вашем союз "и" объединяет предложения с общей вопросительной интонацией.

Правило: Если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой побудительные, вопросительные или восклицательные предложения; объединяющей здесь оказывается интонация, а в побудительных предложениях могут быть и общие частицы: ***Где будет собрание и кто его председатель?***

[См.Академический справочник.](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)

Comment: Не знаю как выделять члены в вопросительных предложениях: "делать" и "нужнопринести"? Если убрать вопрос: "Теперь мне делать машину() и до пятого числа нужно принести справку" - здесь запятая нужна будет? "Теперь" не является здесь обобщающими словом, я думаю. "Делать" и "Принести" будут однородными сказуемыми?

Comment: "И нужно ли вообще?" - имеется в виду "нужно ли приносить документы" А так получается, что оно относится ко всему идущему перед ним предложению, содержащему два вопроса: "что теперь делать?" и "до какого числа нужно принести документы?".

Comment: См. основной ответ.

Comment: Т.к ''нужно" в последнем предложении, то в новом предложении ясно, что он относится к последнему предложению. Можно, конечно, оформить как одно предложение, но зачем нагромождать предложение тремя вопросительными интонациями?

Answer (score 1):

Что мне теперь делать, и до какого числа нужно принести документы, и нужно ли вообще?

Все правила об общем члене (в том числе интонации) относится к одиночным союзами И/ИЛИ),а здесь союз И  повторяется со второго предложения.

Интонация  такого предложения не отличаются от интонации бессоюзного предложения:Что мне теперь делать, до какого числа нужно принести документы, нужно ли вообще?

Comment: Вера, а что , вы произносите эти предложения с перечислительной паузой? Во второй части предложения после союза интонация поднимается. Если поставить запятую, то получится нисходящая интонация.

Comment: Разговорная речь всегда стремится к лаконичности. А с запятыми получается длинная интонация, которую нужно произнести на одном дыхании. После документы явная пауза ощущается, предложение заканчивается.

Comment: Предложение состоит из трех фраз, разделенными паузами, все фразы восходящего тона. Конечно, содержание сообщения можно передать различным образом, но мы же работаем с конкретным (предложенным) вариантом.

Answer (score 0):

semio, здесь письменная фиксация устной речи, в таких случаях дать однозначный ответ по пунктуации бывает сложно. Тут могут быть авторские знаки - не в том, смысле, что они вопреки правилам поставлены, а в том, что автор их может выбрать в зависимости от желаемого смысла.

Прежде всего, не совсем понятно, как сохранить здесь одно предложение, когда задаются сразу три вопроса. Если это непринципиально, то конечно надо разбить на два (а то и на три) предложения.

Но если нельзя, то я бы написал так.

***Что мне теперь делать, и до какого числа нужно принести документы - и нужно ли вообще?***

Достаточных оснований опустить первую запятую я не вижу, а вот вторую логично оформить как-то по-особенному, чтобы выделить из ряда. тире в функции противопоставления дает такую возможность.

Comment: Серж, я не веду с Вами полемики в таком тоне, Вы это знаете. Мне уже предупреждение админ вынес. Но сейчас отвечу. Мне недостаточно того, что Вы **упомянули** про правило - и механически перенесли его на рассматриваемый случай. Здесь нет условий для прямого применения этого правила, а обсуждать с Вами Ваши натяжки - себе дороже.

Comment: Во-первых, не нужно искать грубый тон там, где его нет. Во-вторых, я ничего механически не переносил. Я ориентируюсь на правила.

Comment: У Розенталя сказано: В некоторых случаях представляется возможным находить какие-то соотношения между конструкциями разговорной речи и конструкциями речи книжной (кодифицированного литературного языка), проводить аналогию между теми и другими. Но иногда такое сопоставление невозможно и приходится искать особые критерии для решения вопроса о знаках препинания в текстах, отражающих разговорную речь.

Comment: Этого мне достаточно, чтобы не ставить запятую. Впрочем, с вами спорить не буду.

Comment: behemothus, хочу выяснить, чем по сути является "и нужно ли (это) вообще", - присоединительной конструкцией? А первую запятую разве нельзя объяснить общей вопросительной интонацией? Если попробовать переделать это предложение под повествовательное: "Мне теперь делать машину и до 5 числа нужно ходить в больницу". Для удобства взял оба инфинитива несовершенного вида, и если такое построение возможно, то как объяснить наличие/отсутствие запятой?

Comment: Вот такую конструкцию вспомнил: "как мне быть() и что мне делать?"

Comment: Хороший вопрос... Я трактую как самостоятельное предложение с опущенной частью "и нужно ли вообще [это делать]"? Если трактовать как присоединительную, то Серж может быть и прав насчет первой запятой. Поэтому тут можно трактовать или как ряд "однородных" вопросов или как два предложения, второе из которых в свою очередь состоит мз двух частей.

Comment: "как мне быть() и что мне делать?" - здесь я бы поставил. Просто чтобы подчеркнуть, что это два разных вопроса. Но если такого противопоставления не предполагается, то действительно может быть привлечено соображение об общем смысле аопроса - и тогда запятая не требуется. Т.е. опять - на откуп автору.

Comment: Вот насчет этих "однородных" вопросов. Я путаю два, как бы, отдельных и самостоятельных вопроса, например: "как (мне) быть?" и "что (мне)делать?" с однородными сказуемыми из правил русского языка, т.е. "быть" и "делать" я посчитал однородными сказуемыми, выраженными одной частью речи и отвечающими на одинаковые вопросы (кроме глаголов - они могут отвечать на разные вопросы). Так же и в изначальном предложении: "теперь делать" и "нужно принести" я посчитал именно однородными сказуемыми - это ведь ошибочно так считать?